# ASP.NET Forms auth - gettings user data

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I'm using forms authentication on a very small ASP.NET web app (Web Forms) in which I want to store additional info about the user in a separate database table.

This is then linked back to the `aspnet_User` table and I was figuring the best column to link to is the `UserId` column. Problem is I can't work out how to get this piece of data when the user is logged in. Is it even possible?

Also, how do I get the email address?

---

Before someone points it out, I am aware of the ProfileProvider but the details stored need to be re-submitted each year (it's a registration application for a sporting club) and all previous data stored. So the ProfileProvider isn't really applicable (unless I'm wrong and it can be used to have it stored *historically*?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's how you can get the userid

```
MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
string UserID = myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
string Email = myObject.Email;
```